# Replacing HP ML30 G10 Processor

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant, central-processing-unit, hpe

Dears,

I currently have the HPE ML30 G10 with Intel® Xeon® E-2124 processor installed in it. I wonder if it is possible to replace the processor with Intel® Xeon® E-2288G or Intel® Xeon® E-2236 without changing/replacing any other components inside the server ?

Thanks,

Comment: Doesn't look good from a comparison: https://askgeek.io/en/cpus/vs/Intel_Xeon-E-2288G-vs-Intel_Xeon-E-2124  Why not ask HP directly for a replacement part compatibility list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the newest quickSpecs and it mentions that this particulate model supports up to 6 cores and Intel® Xeon® E-2236 is on the supported CPU list.

[https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docLocale=en_US&docId=emr_na-a00061354en_us#:~:text=Supports%20latest%20Intel%20Xeon%20E,Memory%20UDIMM%20offering%208GB%2C%2016GB](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docLocale=en_US&docId=emr_na-a00061354en_us#:%7E:text=Supports%20latest%20Intel%20Xeon%20E,Memory%20UDIMM%20offering%208GB%2C%2016GB).

Comment: Keep in mind that if processors are added to the list after the hardware was initially shipped, then a BIOS update may be required _before_ installing the new CPU.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks for the info

Answer (score 3):

Here's the quickspecs (https://h20195.www2.hpe.com/v2/getdocument.aspx?docname=a00053821enus)

It doesn't show any 22xx-series CPU as compatible.

Comment: But both processors use the same FCLGA1151 socket, shouldn't that be sufficient enough in terms of comparability?

Comment: But they're not supported, so obviously not.